# sql - How to select so that the row can be column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
   Item      Name             Name_location   Price

    1      item1_london        london         10
    1      item1_beijing       bejing         10
    2      item2_london        london         20
    2      item2_beijing       bejing         20
```

Basically, this table means I have lots of items, `each item will have a different name in different location (two locations: london and beijing)`.

**How can I query** so that I can get the table like this:

```
  Item     london             bejing          Price
    1      item1_london       item1_beijing    10
    2      item2_london       item2_beijing    20
```

I am using MS SQL Server.

**Edit: updated the two tables, add another column**

Comment: Will you only ever have two locations?

Comment: @bluefeet yes. at least for now.

Comment: You will need to use PIVOT here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: see my edit, even though you only have two locations at this point, I added a dynamic version as well in the event you ever have an unknown number of locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
select * 
from YourTable src
pivot (max(name) for name_location in ([london], [beijing]) ) p
```

Comment: What if I have one more column which should be unchanged? please see edit.

Comment: @JacksonTale No different - as long as price is dependent on ItemId which it appears from your data (which does reflect a flaw in your data structures). If they are different, then you'll get more rows.

Comment: Thanks. What if the original table is a result from a join?

Comment: @JacksonTale Just replace `YourTable` with `(select whatever...)`

Answer (score 4):

If you only have two locations, then you can use a `CASE` statement with aggregate:

**CASE with Aggregate**:

```
select item,
  max(case when Name_location = 'london' then name end) london,
  max(case when Name_location = 'bejing' then name end) bejing,
  sum(price) price
from yourtable
group by item
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1792/2)

or

```
select item,
  max(case when Name_location = 'london' then name end) london,
  max(case when Name_location = 'bejing' then name end) bejing,
  price
from yourtable
group by item, price
```

Using the `PIVOT` function, there are two ways either static/dynamic:

**Static PIVOT**

```
select item, [london], [bejing], price
from 
(
  select item, name, name_location, price
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  max(name)
  for name_location in ([london], [bejing])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93c2a/4)

While the static `PIVOT` versions will work great if you have an known number of values, if you have an unknown number then you can use dynamic sql:

**Dynamic Pivot**:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name_location) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT item,' + @cols + ', price from 
             (
                select item, name, name_location, price
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(name)
                for name_location in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93c2a/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.Item, l.itemName as London, b.ItemName as Beijing
FROM myTable o inner join myTable l ON o.item = l.item
INNER JOIN myTable b ON o.item = b.item
WHERE l.location = 'london' AND b.location = 'beijing'
```

SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93c2a/8

Comment: The modified/tested SQL is pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
select item,london,beijing
from t1
pivot(max(Name) for Name_location in (london, beijing)) pvt
```

[image]

```
select item,london,beijing,price
from t1
pivot(max(Name) for Name_location in (london, beijing)) pvt
```

Comment: What if I have one more column which should be unchanged? please see edit.